# python multiprocessing with map_sync - catching problems

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I trying to use the multiprocessing package in python.

I have code that is designed to generate output based on a collection dates that are passed to multiple processors...

```
years = [2013]
days = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
months = [8]
hours = [0, 6, 12, 18]
ens = [1, 2, 3, 4]

nens = len(days) * len(hours)
hour = hours * len(days)

year  = years * len(days) * len(hours)
month = months * len(days) * len(hours)

temp =[]
for d in days:
    temp.append([d]*len(hours))
day = [x for sublist in temp for x in sublist]
hour = hours * len(days)    
nens = ens * len(days)
```

In this example I have 260 times that are passed to different processors.

`t1 = c[:].map_sync(doCoolStuff, year, month, day, hour, nens, [options] * len(day) )`

There are times when one of the days has missing/incomplete data. When that happens it kills all of the processes on the other nodes. Is there a way to catch these instances? I am not sure a try/except works here.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused by what you're actually calling. You say you're using "map_sync", but that's not a valid pool method. Are you using map_async? The parameters you're passing to it seem to suggesting you're actually using apply_async, since it doesn't look like the second argument (year) is an iterable.

Comment: Thank you for checking in.... the variables being passed in (year, month, day, hour, and nens) all have the same length (year  = years * len(days) * len(hours)). In the example here each is a list with length of 40.

Comment: Ok..I'm still a little confused by `c[:].map_sync(`. Where are c and map_sync defined?

Comment: They are defined in the block just before the code I provided 'code'                                               from IPython.parallel import Client  
    c = Client(profile='default')  
    dview = c[:]  
    dview.apply_sync(lambda: "Starting Nodes!")  
    print dview.apply_sync(lambda: "Starting Nodes!")

Comment: Oh, you're using IPython.parallel, not the Python multiprocessing module. That explains why your call looked incorrect. I have a solution for the multiprocessing module, but I've never used IPython.parallel before, and a quick look at their API shows they don't have an equivalent to the multiprocessing module my solution uses. I'll see if I can think of another way using IPython.parallel.

Comment: My error is phrasing the question incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options here. One is to make sure the doCoolStuff function never throws an exception, and instead returns None or something else that indicates an error occurred. The other option is to use imap instead of map_sync, and loop over the iterator one element at a time, inside of a try/except block.

```
it = c[:].imap(doCoolStuff, year, month, day, hour, nens, [options] * len(day))
t1 = []
while True:
    try:
        t1.append(it.next())
    except StopIteration:
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print "Caught an exception: %s" % e
```

This approach works with multiprocessing module, and it seems like IPython does have an equivalent (http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.parallel.client.view.html), so it should work for that as well.

**Edit:**
If you go with the first option, you can remove whatever result is returned when an exception is caught (None, [], or any other value where `bool(value) == False`) from your final list like this:

```
t1 = filter(None, c[:].map_sync(doCoolStuff, year,...))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have used a variant of your second suggestion without an issue. However I would like to solve the parallel issue. "doCoolStuff" throws no exceptions. It returns a list of information. The code, as written, takes the date information that is passed in and reads files with that date... and then does that stuff. I assume the issue that there are times when the files are either missing or otherwise incomplete. I suppose I could add a try/except to doCoolStuff which returns an empty list.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying doCoolStuff doesn't directly raise any exception (meaning you haven't actually written `raise Exception(..)` anywhere), but exceptions are being raised while it's running because the files its trying to process are missing/incomplete?

Comment: Correct. Nowhere does raise Exception or try/except get called anywhere.

Comment: Ok, if you'd prefer to prevent any exceptions from leaving doCoolStuff, and leave the map call the way it is, you can do that, too. I'll edit my answer to show how you can do that an filter out the empty lists that are returned when the exception is caught in doCoolStuff.

Comment: Looking forward to it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and received the following message:    ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: I tried your suggestion and received the following message:    ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().                                                             when data was missing I got the following: IndexError: list index out of range